# Iterate through the XML based on count and create ArrayString using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

parse the XML by iterating through loop and create array of string using loops

```
<USR_ORD><OrderResponse>
<OrderCount1>3</OrderCount1>
<OrderResult><orders>
<order>
<name>A</name><address>AAA</address><number>A1</number><status></status>
</order>
<order>
<name>B</name><number>B1</number>
</order>
<order>
<name>C</name><address>CCC</address><number>C1</number><status></status>
</order>
</orders></OrderResult>
</OrderResponse></USR_ORD>
```

**My Code is as follows**

```
//creating list
val myList=List((100,1,"<USR_ORD><OrderResponse><OrderCount1>3</OrderCount1><OrderResult><orders><order><name>A</name><address>AAA</address><number>A1</number><status></status></order><order><name>B</name><number>B1</number></order><order><name>C</name><address>CCC</address><number>C1</number><status></status></order></orders></OrderResult></OrderResponse></USR_ORD>"))

//creating dataframe and temp table
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(myList);
val DF1 = rdd.toDF("customer_id","response_id","response_output")
DF1.createOrReplaceTempView("ord_tbl");

spark.sql("""select * from ord_tbl""").show(10,false)
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|customer_id|response_id|response_output                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|100        |1          |<USR_ORD><OrderResponse><OrderCount1>3</OrderCount1><OrderResult><orders><order><name>A</name><address>AAA</address><number>A1</number><status></status></order><order><name>B</name><number>B1</number></order><order><name>C</name><address>CCC</address><number>C1</number><status></status></order></orders></OrderResult></OrderResponse></USR_ORD>|
+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**using xpath standard function**

```
spark.sql("""select xpath(response_output, '/USR_ORD/OrderResponse/OrderResult/orders/order/name/text()') as name
      ,xpath(response_output, '/USR_ORD/OrderResponse/OrderResult/orders/order/address/text()') as address
      , xpath(response_output, '/USR_ORD/OrderResponse/OrderResult/orders/order/status/text()') as status from ord_tbl""").show(10,false)
+---------+----------+------+
|name     |address   |status|
+---------+----------+------+
|[A, B, C]|[AAA, CCC]|[]    |
+---------+----------+------+
```

**but Expected Dataframe should be like below**

```
+---------+----------+------+
|name     |address   |status|
+---------+----------+------+
|[A, B, C]|[AAA,,CCC]|[,,]  |
+---------+----------+------+
```

Something I tried using loop for reference, which I am sure wrong and not compiling

```
def (inorders:Int,inOrderCount:int,partxpathstring1:String,partxpathstring2:String,)
val orders=inorders
val OrderCount=inOrderCount
var i=0
var j=0
for (i <- 1 to orders){
    for(j <- 1 to OrderCount){
    fullxpath=xpath_string(response_output,'$partxpathstring1+[i]+$partxpathstring2+[j]')
    fullxpath+=fullxpath
    )
j+=1
    }
i+1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark's `xpath` function seems to filter empty values in the XML nodes. You might need to use UDF to handle this. Here's an example using `scala.xml.XML` to parse the column `response_output`:

```
val parse_orders = udf((response: String) => {
  val xml = scala.xml.XML.loadString(response)

  val orderCount = (xml \\ "USR_ORD" \ "OrderResponse" \ "OrderCount1").text
  val orders = xml \\ "USR_ORD" \ "OrderResponse" \ "OrderResult" \ "orders" \ "order"

  val orderInfo = Seq("name", "address", "number", "status").map { node =>
    (node -> (orders \ node).map(_.text))
  }.toMap

  (orderCount, orderInfo)
})


val df1 = df.withColumn("parsed", parse_orders(col("response_output")))
  .select(
    col("customer_id"),
    col("response_id"),
    col("parsed._1").as("orderCount"),
    col("parsed._2.name").as("name"),
    col("parsed._2.address").as("address"),
    col("parsed._2.number").as("number"),
    col("parsed._2.status").as("status")
  )  

df1.show(false)
//+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+------------+------+
//|customer_id|response_id|orderCount|name     |address     |number      |status|
//+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+------------+------+
//|100        |1          |3         |[A, B, C]|[AAA, , CCC]|[A1, B1, C1]|[, , ]|
//+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+------------+------+
```

Comment: Hi @blackbishop I am accepting this solution but this is also not working in my case as the above solution works only if the xml length is below 28544 and this is breaking once we exceed the that xml length, unfortunately in my case the xml I am dealing is of length 319989. any other way to solve this.

Comment: Hi @pythonsparkscala, this is for small XML strings parsing. I advise you to use `spark-xml` if you deal with large XMLs.